# Get geolocation and save it to text file

Tags: javascript, php, html, geolocation

Hello I have this code and I want to get latitude and longitude of the guest and save them to a text file after click the button

this the code what I used
thank you

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,errorCallback, { timeout:5000 });
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    var latlong = x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;

//document.location='http://192.168.0.100:4321/'+latlong;
}

function errorCallback(error) {
x.innerHTML = "failed";
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```